# get everything before second dot sql

Tags: sql, hive

I would like to obtain everything in a column (column name: test) before the second decimal/dot. The column is in string format.

Example: Data in column test

```
 a bc.de.fg
 k.l.o.p
```

Desired Output

```
a bc.de
k.l
```

Comment: use `charindex` twice

Comment: See below and replace 'a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p' with your column name.

Comment: You may want to consider adding a [strtok()](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/811473/A-Transact-Sql-version-of-C-strtok-using-a-table-v) function if this is something you run into often (Splitting a field by a delimiter and accessing a substring at a certain position)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Java-based user-defined function and pass as a parameter a column.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

class UdfClass extends UDF {
    public String evaluate(String input) {
        String arr[]= input.split(".");
        return arr[0]+=arr[1];
    }
}
```

You will need to create a function in Hive:

```
 add jar /path/to/youJar.jar;
 create temporary function new_function_name as 'jar_class_name';
```

After that you will be able to query like:

```
select new_function_name(test) from teble_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
select 
left((left('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p' , len('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p')-charindex('.', reverse('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p'))) )
 , len((left('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p' , len('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p')-charindex('.', reverse('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p'))) )
 )-charindex('.', reverse((left('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p' , len('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p')-charindex('.', reverse('a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p'))) ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `locate` function we can finding out in two iterations, the position of the second "." and then using `substr`, we can get the content of string from position 1 to the number we arrived at.

```
select 
substr("a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p"
,1
,locate(
      substr("a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p", 
             locate("a bc.de.fg k.l.o.p" ,".") +1
          ,1000
      )
      ,"."
) - 1
)
```